# Creating TypeScript Declaration File without Altering Existing JavaScript Code

Tags: typescript

We have a fair amount of javascript that we would like to start bringing into the TypeScript world. Ideally, we would be able to create TypeScript declaration files without having to alter existing javascript code.

Below is a tiny snippet of code from Microsoft's Ajax Timer that is very much in line with the type of code that we would like to create declaration files for.

I've spent several hours trying to create a declaration file that makes TypeScript happy, but it really hasn't worked out well to this point.

How would a declaration file for the following code look?

```js
  Type.registerNamespace("Nmspc");

  Nmspc.Timer = function () {
    Nmspc.Timer.initializeBase(this);

    this._interval = 1000;
    this._enabled = false;
    this._timer = null;
  };

  Nmspc.Timer.prototype = {
    get_interval: function() {
      return this._interval;
    },
    set_interval: function(value) {
      if (this._interval !== value) {
        // snip
      }
    },

    get_enabled: function() {
      return this._enabled;
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

If your code organization would follow the [external modules](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries) pattern and your module loader would be the `amd` then

**(1)** transacript of your code into `Timer.ts` might look like this:

```
class Timer {
  private _interval: number;
  private _enabled: boolean;
  private _timer: any;

  constructor() {
    // super();

    this._interval = 1000;
    this._enabled = false;
    this._timer = null;
  }

  get_interval(): number {
    return this._interval;
  }

  set_interval(value: number): void {
    if (this._interval !== value) {
      // snip
    }
  }

  get_enabled(): boolean {
    return this._enabled;
  }
}

export = Timer;
```

and **(2)** command

`tsc Timer.ts --declaration --module amd`

would **(3)** generate `Timer.d.ts` which would look like this:

```
declare class Timer {
    private _interval;
    private _enabled;
    private _timer;
    constructor();
    get_interval(): number;
    set_interval(value: number): void;
    get_enabled(): boolean;
}
export = Timer;
```

The proper encoding depends on how the rest of your code base consumes the JavaScript parts of the code. Examples in https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped are certainly a good guides

Another possible hand-made encoding with **(4)** interfaces might look like:

```
interface ITimer {
    get_interval(): number;
    set_interval(value: number): void;
    get_enabled(): boolean;
}
interface Nmspc {
    Timer: {
        new(): ITimer;
    }
}
```

Comment: @basarat yes, this time I was faster then you :)

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. I have not been able to make it work without changing existing code though. I'm going to make some time tonight to try to create the simplest repeatable bit of code that is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you?

```
declare module Nmspc {
    export class Timer {
        public interval: number;
        public enabled: boolean;
    }
}
```